# Split string using regex python

Tags: python, regex

```
80 x 59 x 53 108 x 98 x 73
```

I want to split this string into

```
80 x 59 x 53 and 108 x 98 x 73
```

There could be any number of spaces in between any characters

Please help me to solve this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to print `and` also in the middle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind and positive lookahead `regex`:

```
import re

s = '80 x 59 x 53 108 x 98 x 73'
print(re.split(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)', s))

# ['80 x 59 x 53', '108 x 98 x 73']
```

If you're concerned about `and` in-between:

```
print(' and '.join(re.split(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)', s)))

# 80 x 59 x 53 and 108 x 98 x 73
```

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment.